# &decltype(obj)::member not working

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member, decltype

Why is does this not work (Visual C++ 2012 Update 1), and what is the proper way to fix it?

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
namespace bll = boost::lambda;

struct Adder
{
    int m;
    Adder(int m = 0) : m(m) { }
    int foo(int n) const { return m + n; }
};

#define bindm(obj, f, ...)  bind(&decltype(obj)::f, obj, __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    return bll::bindm(Adder(5), foo, bll::_1)(5);
}
```

Comment: Works with gcc and clang++

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774053/decltype-obj-member-doesnt-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`decltype` as a *nested-name-specifier* was added into C++11 at a relatively late stage; [n3049](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3049.pdf) as the resolution to [DR 743](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#743) (and [DR 950](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#950)).  n3049 was published in March 2010, which is probably why it hasn't found its way into VC++ yet.

The workaround is to use the identity typefunction:

```
template<typename T> using id = T;
id<decltype(expression)>::member;
```

Comment: Sadly enough no template typedefs either for VC11. But `std::common_type<...>::type` should do the same.

Comment: VC++ includes the no-longer-existent `std::identity<>` metafunction for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

A compiler bug.

A *decltype-specifier* (7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]) is explicitly allowed as a *nested-name-speficier* (5.1 Primary expressions [expr.prim] -> 5.1.1 General expr.prim.general] #8)

PS. After the @ecatmur's idea:

```
template<typename T> struct id { typedef T type; };

#define bindm(obj, f, ...)  bind(&id<decltype(obj)>::type::f, obj, __VA_ARGS__)
```